# Post title not displaying as recorded in the wp_posts table

Tags: posts, title, wp-title, get-the-title

I have a WordPress install in which the "post_title" field from the "wp_posts" table is not making it into the WP_Post->post_title variable.

So, for a given post in the wp_posts table that has a correct post_title value of say (retrieved via a direct MySQL query):

```
"My First Post"
```

Retrieving the post title via any basic WordPress method, such as:

```
<?php print the_title(); ?>
```

... or ...

```
<?php
$this_post = get_post();
print $this_post->post_title; 
?>
```

Instead of the post's title I get something like:

```
"Category | Sitename"
```

(Where "Category" is something like "Articles" and "Sitename" is the site's name)

The resulting string from querying the post's tile is not the contents of the post_title field from the record in the wp_post table, ie. it's NOT the post's title.

I would expect to see the post's title here because the documentation for the WP_Post object (https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wp_post/) states that the post_title member contains the post's title, however it clearly does not, it contains some other value.

I've searched for any references to a filter which might be rewriting the post title, but as of yet can find none.

How is it possible that WordPress might be returning something other than the actual post title when referencing the post title? Where else should I be looking?

Comment: Can you give an example of what the title should be, and what the title is displaying as, and where that data comes from? How are you testing this? WordPress won't behave this way by default. Did you revert to the default theme and disable all plugins then re-activate them 1 by 1 until the problem returned?

Comment: Thanks for the quick feedback @TomJNowell . I've made some changes to the post. I cannot revert the theme, this is an existing production site with a custom theme. I'm aware that WordPress has some unintuitive behaviours when it comes to site titles, but I'm struggling to find canonical documentation on this when Googling it, only anecdotal mentions. The developer documentation for the relevant classes seems largely quiet and even misleading in the matter, from what I can see thus far.

Comment: does your custom theme have any filter functions acting on 'the_title'?

Comment: @Michael none that I can find with a half decent grep.

Comment: extend the search and include all plugins;

Comment: @Michael a general question: normally when a post is queried, and aside from any "add_filter" intervention, shouldn't the WP_Post->post_title value be populated by the post_title field as stored in the wp_posts table?

Comment: @paulswanson did you disable everything then turn it on 1 by 1 like I suggested? **Again, this is not standard WP behaviour**, something else is doing this. You need to identify the plugin or theme that is causing this. Disable everything back to vanilla WP with a default theme, then start turning things back on 1 by 1